# Boost coroutine won't compile because of ambiguous call to callcc

Tags: c++, boost, coroutine

I'm trying to use coroutines in a C++ project at work.  However, it will not compile because of an ambiguous use of `callcc()`.  I have tried specifying allocators in the coroutine constructor, but that doesn't seem to make a speck of difference.

After stripping down the code to its barest essentials I ended up reproducing the problem with something very similar to the fibbonacci examples from the boost documentation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/coroutine2/all.hpp>

/*
    c++ -std=c++11 -o corofib corofib.cpp
*/

typedef boost::coroutines2::coroutine<unsigned long> coro_t;

coro_t::pull_type generator(
    [](coro_t::push_type& sink) {
        unsigned long first = 1L;
        unsigned long second = 1L;
        unsigned long answer;

        sink(first);
        sink(second);
        while(1) {
            answer = first + second;
            first = second;
            second = answer;
            sink(answer);
        };
    }
);


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    generator();
    std::cout << generator.get() << std::endl;
    generator();
    std::cout << generator.get() << std::endl;
    generator();
    std::cout << generator.get() << std::endl;
    generator();
    std::cout << generator.get() << std::endl;
}
```

I am using:

- Boost 1.64
- gcc version 4.9.2
- Linux delegato 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP
  Debian 3.16.39-1+deb8u2 (2017-03-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Here's the error messages I'm getting.  I've removed the "required from" notices in an attempt to shorten this post:

```
lear@delegato:~/lamu$ c++ -std=c++14 -o corofib corofib.cpp
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/coroutine2/detail/coroutine.hpp:48:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/coroutine2/coroutine.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/coroutine2/all.hpp:10,
                 from corofib.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/boost/coroutine2/detail/pull_control_block_cc.ipp: In instantiation of ‘boost::coroutines2::detail::pull_coroutine<T>::control_block::control_block(boost::context::preallocated, StackAllocator, Fn&&) [with StackAllocator = boost::context::basic_fixedsize_stack<boost::context::stack_traits>; Fn = <lambda(boost::coroutines2::coroutine<long unsigned int>::push_type&)>; T = long unsigned int]’:
/usr/local/include/boost/coroutine2/detail/pull_control_block_cc.ipp:105:14: error: call of overloaded ‘callcc(const std::allocator_arg_t&, boost::context::preallocated&, boost::context::basic_fixedsize_stack<boost::context::stack_traits>&, boost::coroutines2::detail::pull_coroutine<T>::control_block::control_block(boost::context::preallocated, StackAllocator, Fn&&) [with StackAllocator = boost::context::basic_fixedsize_stack<boost::context::stack_traits>; Fn = <lambda(boost::coroutines2::coroutine<long unsigned int>::push_type&)>; T = long unsigned int]::<lambda(boost::context::continuation&&)>)’ is ambiguous
             });
              ^
/usr/local/include/boost/coroutine2/detail/pull_control_block_cc.ipp:105:14: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/coroutine2/detail/pull_control_block_cc.hpp:14:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/coroutine2/detail/coroutine.hpp:37,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/coroutine2/coroutine.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/coroutine2/all.hpp:10,
                 from corofib.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/boost/context/continuation.hpp:469:1: note: boost::context::continuation boost::context::callcc(std::allocator_arg_t, StackAlloc, Fn&&, Arg ...) [with StackAlloc = boost::context::preallocated; Fn = boost::context::basic_fixedsize_stack<boost::context::stack_traits>&; Arg = {boost::coroutines2::detail::pull_coroutine<T>::control_block::control_block(boost::context::preallocated, StackAllocator, Fn&&) [with StackAllocator = boost::context::basic_fixedsize_stack<boost::context::stack_traits>; Fn = <lambda(boost::coroutines2::coroutine<long unsigned int>::push_type&)>; T = long unsigned int]::<lambda(boost::context::continuation&&)>}]
 callcc( std::allocator_arg_t, StackAlloc salloc, Fn && fn, Arg ... arg) {
 ^
/usr/local/include/boost/context/continuation.hpp:483:1: note: boost::context::continuation boost::context::callcc(std::allocator_arg_t, boost::context::preallocated, StackAlloc, Fn&&, Arg ...) [with StackAlloc = boost::context::basic_fixedsize_stack<boost::context::stack_traits>; Fn = boost::coroutines2::detail::pull_coroutine<T>::control_block::control_block(boost::context::preallocated, StackAllocator, Fn&&) [with StackAllocator = boost::context::basic_fixedsize_stack<boost::context::stack_traits>; Fn = <lambda(boost::coroutines2::coroutine<long unsigned int>::push_type&)>; T = long unsigned int]::<lambda(boost::context::continuation&&)>; Arg = {}]
 callcc( std::allocator_arg_t, preallocated palloc, StackAlloc salloc, Fn && fn, Arg ... arg) {
 ^
/usr/local/include/boost/context/continuation.hpp:514:1: note: boost::context::continuation boost::context::callcc(std::allocator_arg_t, boost::context::preallocated, StackAlloc, Fn&&) [with StackAlloc = boost::context::basic_fixedsize_stack<boost::context::stack_traits>; Fn = boost::coroutines2::detail::pull_coroutine<T>::control_block::control_block(boost::context::preallocated, StackAllocator, Fn&&) [with StackAllocator = boost::context::basic_fixedsize_stack<boost::context::stack_traits>; Fn = <lambda(boost::coroutines2::coroutine<long unsigned int>::push_type&)>; T = long unsigned int]::<lambda(boost::context::continuation&&)>]
 callcc( std::allocator_arg_t, preallocated palloc, StackAlloc salloc, Fn && fn) {
 ^
/usr/local/include/boost/context/continuation.hpp:457:1: note: boost::context::continuation boost::context::callcc(Fn&&, Arg ...) [with Fn = const std::allocator_arg_t&; Arg = {boost::context::preallocated, boost::context::basic_fixedsize_stack<boost::context::stack_traits>, boost::coroutines2::detail::pull_coroutine<T>::control_block::control_block(boost::context::preallocated, StackAllocator, Fn&&) [with StackAllocator = boost::context::basic_fixedsize_stack<boost::context::stack_traits>; Fn = <lambda(boost::coroutines2::coroutine<long unsigned int>::push_type&)>; T = long unsigned int]::<lambda(boost::context::continuation&&)>}; <template-parameter-1-3> = void]
 callcc( Fn && fn, Arg ... arg) {
```

I think the code is basically sound: I just need to dis-ambiguate this somehow.

I could say something about how easy this is to do in python, but it might incite laughter.

Comment: Not your problem but identifiers ending in `_t` are reserved for POSIX.

Comment: Interesting -- playing with this on Wandbox, this compiles on GCC 5.4.0 and newer, or with previous version of Boost. Seems like a regression in the recent release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Boost.Context, which was [reported](https://github.com/boostorg/context/issues/52) and [fixed](https://github.com/boostorg/context/pull/55) upstream. You can find a patch that is specifically targeted for Boost 1.64 [here](https://github.com/boostorg/context/pull/54#issuecomment-296149214).

Comment: This answer, and the comment from Dan Mašek, led me to upgrade my dev compiler to GCC 6.2.  Problem solved.  We're using gcc 6.2 in our linux distro builds, so this is a better version to use anyway.